# Is there an alternate estimator for a sample covariance matrix when n < p such that the estimator is not singular

Tags: covariance, estimators, multivariate-normal-distribution, svd, singular-matrix

Let's say I have $n$ samples which are vectors of length $p$. I know that the $p \times p$ sample covariance matrix is singular if $n \leq p$. Is there another estimator for the covariance that results in a non-singular matrix when $n \leq p$?

My goal is to estimate covariance from many datasets and then quickly sample from a multivariate Gaussian using the estimated covariance. I know this can be done using SVD even if the matrix is singular, but $p$ in my problem is very large and I am estimating thousands of covariance matrices (which would require computing SVD on thousands of matrices with large $p$. This problem is tractable with Cholesky but this requires a PSD covaraince matrix.

Comment: Does this help?: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173311/estimation-of-the-covariance-matrix?rq=1

Comment: "requires a PSD covaraince matrix" every covariance matrix is positive semidefinite; I'm assuming you mean Cholesky is failing because of the *semi* in semidefinite. If so, you may wish to look into the Pivoted Cholesky Decomposition, which can accomodate singular matrices. Regarding an alternative estimator of the covariance which is always nonsingular, one solution would be to use a Bayesian posterior mean, say, using a Wishart prior perhaps.